# SQL Joining tables and displaying data

Tags: sql, join

I have 3 tables to do with hospitals which I am having trouble with.

[image: http://postimage.org/image/hi2c4yrrf/]

**Admission** Contains patientid, admitteddate, dischargeddate and ward.
**Doctor** doctorid, Surname, Firstname and ward.
**Ward** wardid, name and consultant (doctorid)

I have been able to do a lot of which the tutorial is asking of me, but I cannot find any guidance or answers on how to do the following:

I wish to find the surnames of the doctors that are not used by a patient and also display surnames of ones used by a patient. I'm guessing join the tables Doctor and Ward and also admission somehow to show that doctor 530 isn't being used by any patient.

I should then have an AND to display the surnames of the doctors who correspond with the consultant in the ward table.

To find the details of the doctors who have not treated any patients i will join Doctor with Ward and display details of those that aren't in the consultant column. I understand this theory, I just am not sure how to work it out in SQL properly.

I welcome any discussion or help with the answers please as I would really like to understand this step.

Comment: There are way too many questions here for one post. Break this apart into smaller issues.

Answer (score 0):

**Doctors that are not used by a patient**

```
select distinct d.number, d.surname
from doctor d
left join ward w on w.consultant = d.number
left join admission ad on ad.ward = w.code
left join patient p on p.code = ad.patient
where p.code is null
```

**Doctors that are used by a patient**

```
select distinct d.number, d.surname
from doctor d
join ward w on w.consultant = d.number
join admission ad on ad.ward = w.code
join patient p on p.code = ad.patient
```

**Schema (for test):**

```
select * into patient
from (
  select 'A102' [code], 'Harris' [surname], 'Lucy' [lastname] union all 
  select 'B372', 'Rossini', 'Peter' union all
  select 'B534', 'Johnson', 'Nadia' union all
  select 'B444', 'Johnson', 'Juigi' union all
  select 'S555', 'Rose', 'Jean') as p

select * into admission
from (
  select 'A102' [patient], null [admitted], NULL [discharged], 'A' [ward] union all
  select 'A102', null, NULL, 'A' union all
  select 'S555', null, NULL, 'B' union all
  select 'B444', null, NULL, 'B' union all
  select 'S555', null, NULL, 'A') as ad

select * into doctor
from (
  select 203 [number], 'Black' [surname], 'Peter' [firstname], 'A' [ward] union all
  select 574, 'Blis', 'Mavis', 'B' union all
  select 461, 'Boyne', 'Steve', 'B' union all
  select 530, 'Clark', 'Nicola', 'C' union all
  select 405, 'Mizzi', 'Nicola', 'A' union all
  select 501, 'Mount', 'Mavis', 'A') as d

select * into ward
from (
  select 'A' [code], 'Surgical' [name], 203 [consultant] union all
  select 'B', 'Paediatric', 574 union all
  select 'C', 'Medical', 530) as w
```